# js: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined using

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I wanted to replace `/\r?\n|\r/g` with empty string but got a type error "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined".

```
export function getCupsCredentials() {
    var vcap_services = process.env.VCAP_SERVICES;
    var vcap_servces_as_single_line = vcap_services.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ");
    var vcap_servces_as_json = JSON.parse(vcap_servces_as_single_line)
    var vcap_servces_user_provided = vcap_servces_as_json['user-provided']
    var cups_credentials = vcap_servces_user_provided[0].credentials;
    return cups_credentials;
}
```

i got the following error message on using .replace

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at getCupsCredentials (/app/ui/dist/webpack:/src/utils/VcapUtils.js:4:50)
at Object.defineProperty.value (/app/ui/dist/webpack:/src/utils/IAMUtils.js:5:17)
at __webpack_require__ (/app/ui/dist/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap 713b700ecf31:19:1)
at Object.defineProperty.value (/app/ui/dist/webpack:/src/api/middleware/filters/authFilter.js:1:1)
at __webpack_require__ (/app/ui/dist/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap 713b700ece831:19:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/ui/dist/webpack:/src/api/middleware/pre.js:1:1)
at __webpack_require__ (/app/ui/dist/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap 713b70031:19:1)
at Object.defineProperty.value (/app/ui/dist/webpack:/src/api/middleware/index.js:1:1)
at __webpack_require__ (/app/ui/dist/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap 713b700ececf31:19:1)
at Object.canUseDOM (/app/ui/dist/webpack:/src/server.js:4:1)
Starting Conductor UI
using Conductor API server from 'http://chand-wf-nfce-server.cloud.pcftest.com/api'
 
/app/ui/dist/webpack:/src/utils/VcapUtils.js:4
var vcap_servces_as_single_line = vcap_services.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ");
```

Comment: try console.logging ```vcap_services```, it seems, it does not have any value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these values are getting fetched from a remote server then the case might be that you are trying to replace the characters before the data is assigned to the variable. Try using `await` functions or the `.then()` And also replace as such  `var vcap_servces_as_single_line = vcap_services?.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ");`

So that the code will not scream at you if you have an undefined value.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause is that your `process.env.VCAP_SERVICES` is not initialized properly and it is initializing your `vcap_services` with `undefined`. As the replace method does not work with `undefined` thus that error.

Try checking if `vcap_services` is empty or not by the ternary operator

```
export function getCupsCredentials() {
  var vcap_services = process.env.VCAP_SERVICES;
  var vcap_servces_as_single_line = vcap_services
    ? vcap_services.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, " ")
    : "vcap_servisec is empty";
  console.log(vcap_services);
  /*
    var vcap_servces_as_json = JSON.parse(vcap_servces_as_single_line)
    var vcap_servces_user_provided = vcap_servces_as_json['user-provided']
    var cups_credentials = vcap_servces_user_provided[0].credentials;
    return cups_credentials;
    */
}
```